# Is there a way to change the colors of row and column headers instead of default gray background

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am working in excel sheet. There are some formulas & conditional formatting to check the data entered is correct or not. So i want to show the error that happened in any cell of a row by changing the background colour of the row header.

Is there a way to change the colors of row and column headers instead of default background ?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: If you wanted to achieve something similar, you could use Column A and Row 1 to conditionally change colour based on your logic, using Freeze Panes to ensure this row and column are always visible, like the column/row headers.